# Open GL render active viewport: Sky color disappeared

Tags: transparency, opengl

I have got a sky color as well as a texture set, but since some time the viewport render only shows a transparent or black area behind all objects. I use game engine, but blender render does the same. 
I had that some time before, that there is no sky in the viewport render but I would like to make it visible again. I don't know how to do this, so has anyone got an idea what I could do?

Comment: I'll suggest the obvious here - in Blender itself, press N, open the "Display" tab and make sure "World background" is ticked.  "Only Render" is also a good idea.  In the properties panel at extreme right, open the rendering icon, (little camera at left) then it's "Shading" tab.  The Alpha slot should be set to "Transparent".  The Post Processing tab further down is safest with it's two boxes unticked unless using actually the VSE or Compositor.

Comment: The above locked me out before I could correct the "Transparent" mistake.  That should read "set the "Shading" tab to "Sky" .  Open the "World" icon (little blue globe at top) and it's "Sky" tab, set that to your desired sky colour.

Comment: Thank you very much. The alpha was set to transparent, that was the problem. Now I could solve it^^